# Python GUI development

Tags: python, user-interface

Ok, so im new to python, and have recently acquired a strong grasp of the language, but not great. I have more experience with c++, and when using GUI's, i have used Microsoft visual studios, which makes GUI development relatively easy. I currently have qt designer, and do not like how complicated it is to write th applications. Does anybody know of any software that uses python, and is similar to qt, but allows me to write directly into the GUI software?

Comment: take a look at pyqt I think you will feel right at home ...

Comment: You can try wxPython, along with wxformbuilder (a RAD tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you try [`pyqt`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net)? It seems to be what you are looking for.

> PyQt is the Python bindings for Digia's Qt cross-platform application development framework. It supports Python v2 and v3 and Qt v4 and Qt v5. PyQt is available under the GPL and commercial licenses. The Sourceforge project is the repository for the GPL source and binary packages.